# How do I use the eval statement in tcl

Tags: tcl, evaluation

So basically in my tcl script I generate a line of tcl code that I have to execute( ie I come up with this instruction during runtime). Once I have the tcl instruction say for example puts "hello world $test_var". How do I execute this using tcl?

Do I use the eval command or what?

Answer (score 4):

The `eval` command is a reasonable way of doing this, but you might want to consider using `catch` instead, since that will trap any problems found during the evaluation of the generated code, for example like this:

```
# Generate the code somehow
set variable {puts "hello word $test_var"}

# Execute and trap problems
if {[catch $variable resultMsg]} {
    # An error (or other exception) happened
    puts stderr "BOOM, Error! $resultMsg"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using [eval] which works perfectly well, in newer versions of Tcl you can use the {*} syntax.
For example:

```
set cmd "puts"
lappend cmd "abcd ef"
{*}$cmd
```

Note that it's a good habit to use list commands to build up your command so you wont run into quoting issues.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you don't have another reasonable choice than to use the `eval` command, e.g.:

```
set variable {puts "hello world $test_var"}
eval $variable
```

Comment: Why be afraid? What's to fear?

Comment: In this example there's nothing to fear. But I already had cases in which it was quite hard to deal with `eval` without doing something wrong. Unfortunately I don't remember the exact issue at the moment. It had something to do with correct quoting and as far as I remember it was even a nested `eval` (but at the end it worked correctly).